# Android Jetpack WorkManager data retention policy

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I would like to use the new WorkManager to replace a Service implementation of a phone telemetry sender (to be complaint with Android O).  Right now it's essentially a bound service that tries to send telemetry realtime but if the network fails it will save the record to the DB that will later be replayed to the server when network resumes.  Pretty much the definition of what WorkManager can accomplish with Constraints.

The trouble I have is one of security.  My database is encrypted and it is also completely wiped when the user logs out or asks to wipe their data.  WorkManager is backed by the Room db and stores all payload data in the clear.  Worse yet, it seems they don't expose the ability to delete these records at your whim.  Instead, they offer cancellation which literally just sets a column status to CANCELLED.  I can't find documentation or a code path that would explain a way to overcome this.  Has anyone gotten a chance to explore the library much?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Right. Maybe I'm confused. The WorkSpec class in Work manager defines a room layer that persists your enqueued tasks. It would need this for guaranteed execution later by the OS.  Are you saying there is an API to inject into work manager my own db provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Work Manager I/O Talk](https://youtu.be/IrKoBFLwTN0?t=1729), WorkManager is not meant to be your data store. You should continue to store your data in your own database.

Comment: So is the idea that rather than the parcelled data pass to input you pass an Id to your own indexed storage?  You'd have to incur db read even in the happy path right?

Comment: That's correct - you can't pass Parcelables into WorkManager's `Data` class, so you'd want to use that approach in any case.

Comment: Ah I see. I think having used Yigit's Android-Priority-Jobqueue for so long got me confused. Thanks!

Comment: Quick one, please is the indexed of the record in strorage passed to the work manager persisted even after reboot?

Comment: @PaulOkeke - WorkManager does persist work over reboots, yes.